# show hidden files and folders in project drawer in textmate

Tags: textmate

By default, textmate does not show all files and folders in the project drawer.

how do I make textmate project drawer show hidden files, in particular all files and directories beginning with a dot?

Answer (score 7):

Click `Preferences > Advanced > Folder References`,

Edit `File Pattern` (minimal change to original default):

```
!(/\.(?!\W*)[^/]*|\.(tmproj|o|pyc)|/Icon\r|/svn-commit(\.[2-9])?\.tmp)$
```

as well as `Folder pattern` (minimal change to original default):

```
!.*/(\.(?!\W*)[^/]*|CVS|_darcs|_MTN|\{arch\}|blib|.*~\.nib|.*\.(framework|app|pbproj|pbxproj|xcode(proj)?|bundle))$
```

This only applies to new project folders. For an existing one, you need to edit the pattern after right-clicking on folder reference and choose `Show Information`.

Comment: So much has changed.  Not sure how to apply these to the latest version of TextMate 2.0 (running Yosemite).

Answer (score 7):

7 years later, TextMate (v2.0.6) , shows these options**:**

default "Exclude files matching"**:**
  `{*.{o,pyc&#125;,Icon\r,CVS,_darcs,_MTN,\}arch\},blib,*\~.nib}`
default "Include files matching"**:**
  `{*,.tm_properties,.htaccess}`
Non-text files**:**
  `{*.{ai,bz2,flv,gif,gz,icns,ico,jpg,jpeg,m4v,nib,o,pdf,png,psd,pyc,rtf,scssc,swf,tar,tbz,tgz,tif,tiff,zip},Icon\r}`

To show all hidden (MacOS) files+folders in file-browser pane of TextMate, what needs to be changed **?**

goto TextMate > Preferences > Projects:
change the "Include..." box regex code into this**:**
  `{*,\.*}`
as shown in below:
[image: TextmMate-Preferences-Projects]

Comment: For anyone curious what the original setting (as of ~2021) for "Include files matching," it is `{*,.tm_properties,.htaccess}`. Since both `.tm_properties` and `.htaccess` are hidden files, replacing the original string with `{*,\.*}` will continue to include those two types.

Answer (score 0):

@Viktor Tron's answer is perfect... Just wanted to add this comment (but had a picture, *so I'll add this answer*)...  Once you DO show "invisible" (`.dot`) files via his snazzy regex... you may want to weed some otherwise extraneous files that now clutter your projects hierarchy... Just do it via the specific project folder's "Show Information..." contextual menu...

In this example I want to IGNORE (fucking) `.DS_Store` files.. SO I simply add `!\.DS_Store` to the "File Pattern" section.

[image]